# certmgr.exe command utility location

Tags: wcf, security, ssl

I'am trying to add certificate to `CurrentUser` location using `certmgr` in script:

```
certmgr.exe -add -r LocalMachine -s My -c -n %SERVER_NAME% -r CurrentUser -s TrustedPeople
```

But `certmgr.exe` command utility is not available in Win 7, VS2008 env.
Please tell me where and how to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find certmgr.exe by opening your visualstudio command prompt and typing in certmgr or just search for certmgr.exe in your windows explorer to know its location and use it in your script.

The location would generally be as follows:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin
```

The above location is when you have installed VS.NET 2010 using hte default location during installation.

Comment: Lacks a space: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin"

Comment: I found it at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin

Answer (score 5):

Here are steps if you don't have Visual Studio installed. Should work for Windows 7+ (tested on Windows 10).

1. Install Windows 10 SDK ([download](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/)).
2. Copy `certmgr.exe` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86`.

You can then use `certmgr.exe` on any computer without installing the SDK. Not sure about redistribution license though.

There is also a x64 version, but as far as i can tell x86 version also works for x64-bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

`rundll32.exe cryptext.dll,CryptExtAddCER "path_to_*.crt_file"` should do the trick, then just hit next on a few popups, hard to make silent though, you may have some luck puttng the .crt in location already and merging a .reg from command line, that might be silent.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about certmgr.exe and certmgr.msc, which are different things. However, about the .exe:

> This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio and with the Windows SDK.

*(from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx))*

So reinstall Visual Studio, or download the Windows SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesstion. I downloaded Windows SDK for win 7 and is able to create certificate